# Show uniform convergence of series with |x|

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function where
$$
f(x)=|x|=
\begin{cases}
-x&x\in[-\pi,0[\\
x&x\in[0,\pi]
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(2^nx)/2^n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

My problem is that I can't see why $f(2^
nx)/2^n\neq |x|$. Any help on getting started is appreciated.

Comment: If you put $x = 1$, this leads $u_n = f(2^n)/2^n$. Is this number 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten that $f$ is periodic of period $2\,\pi$. This implies for instance that $f(2^3)=f(8-2\,\pi)=8-2\,\pi$. With this in mind, it is clear that $|f(x)|\le\pi$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ and the series converges uniformly by Weirstrass's $M$-test.